# Relatório com Rotativa mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

Eu estou com dificuldades em gerar um relatório no mvc, usando o rotativa.
O problema é que ele gera o pdf, como se estive ignorando o html, fica todo sem formatação.

ob.: pra formatação do htm, é css em arquivo externo.

Estou chamando desse jeito:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ImprimeRequerimento(int processoId)
    {
        var requerimento = _processoAppServico.ObterRequerimentoProcesso(processoId);
        var v = new ViewAsPdf
        {
            ViewName = "RequerimentoProcesso",
            Model = requerimento               
        };
        return v;
    }
```

html da view:

```html
 @model GestaoProcesso.Aplicacao.ViewModels.ProcessoViewModel

@{    
    Layout = "null";
}

<h2>ObterRequerimento</h2>


<link href="~/Content/relReqProcesso.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="table-wrap col-lg-11">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="modulos" colspan="4">Dados do Processo:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="nomeCampo" colspan="4">Nome do requerente / Razão Social</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="valorCampo" colspan="4">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NomeCLiente)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="nomeCampo">
                            RG
                        </th>
                        <th class="nomeCampo">
                            Orgão
                        </th>
                        <th class="nomeCampo">
                            Data de Emissão
                        </th>
                        <th class="nomeCampo">
                            CPF/CNPJ
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="valorCampo">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Bairro)</td>
                        <td class="valorCampo"></td>
                        <td class="valorCampo"></td>
                        <td class="valorCampo">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Complemento)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="nomeCampo" colspan="4">
                            Endereço / CEP
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="campoCinza" colspan="4">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Rua)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="nomeCampo">
                            Telefone
                        </th>
                        <th class="nomeCampo" colspan="3">
                            Email
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="valorCampo">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Descricao)</td>
                        <td class="valorCampo" colspan="3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Data)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="modulos" colspan="4">Dados do Processo:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="nomeCampo" colspan="2">
                            Registro IPTU
                        </th>
                        <th class="nomeCampo" colspan="2">
                            INSCRIÇÃO MERCANTIL
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="valorCampo" colspan="2"></td>
                        <td class="valorCampo" colspan="2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="modulos" colspan="4">Solicitação do Processo:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="nomeCampo" colspan="4">
                            Assunto
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="valorCampo" colspan="4"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="nomeCampo" colspan="4">
                            Descrição
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="valorCampo" colspan="4" style="height 25vh;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="modulos" colspan="4"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="nomeCampo" colspan="3">
                            Assinatura
                        </th>
                        <th class="nomeCampo">
                            Data
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="valorCampo" colspan="3"><p /></td>
                        <td class="valorCampo"><p /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

e assim é como fica o PDF:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está a View `RequerimentoProcesso`? Pode colocá-la na pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei lá o html da view e um print de como fica o PDF.
vlw

Comment: Pessoal, alguem ja teve um problema parecido, e que pode me ajudar?
Obrigado

Comment: Posso te dar uma resposta, mas envolve trocar o Rotativa por outro pacote. Vai te atender?

Comment: eu to dando uma olhada no reportviewer, mas pode indicar @CiganoMorrisonMendez, sem problemas.

Answer (score -1):

Estou usando o rotativa com arquivo `css` externo pois estou usando `actionAsPdf` e não `ViewAsPDF`, aqui deu certo. 
Eu fiz assim na `view`, como visto nesse trecho abaixo.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/skin/PDFStyle.css" />

<table class="pdf-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Lista.Count; i++)
{
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" style="height: 60px; width:50px;" class="noPadding">
                <img src="~/Content/images/logocourrieros.png" />
            </td>
```

e no controller fiz da seguinte forma:
um botão qualquer botão chama a action `Print`, que chama no `ActionAsPdf`, a action `Index` que carrega minha `view`.

```
public ActionResult Print()
    {
        return new ActionAsPdf("Index");
    }
```

**OBS:** Caso você precise usar o `ViewAsPDF`, achei em pesquisas que a versão 1.6.4 do rotativa está com o problema do css, fiz o downgrade para a versão 1.6.3 só para confirmar, e ele pegou o css direitinho, fica essa dica ai caso queira testar.